# Appending dictionaries to a dataframe

Tags: python, loops

I have a loop within a nested loop that at the end generates 6 dictionaries. Each dictionary has the same key but different values, I would at the end of every iteration to append the dictionary to the same dataframe but it keeps failing.

At the end I would like to have a table with 6 columns plus an index which holds the keys.

This is the idea behind what I'm trying to do:

```
dictionary = dict()
for i in blahh:
    dictionary[i] = dict(zip(blahh['x'][i], blahh['y'][i]))
    df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
    df_final = pd.concat([dictionary, df])
```

I get the error:

```
cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only series and dataframe objs are valid
```

I've included a loop below:

```
letts = [ ('a','b','c'),('e','f','g'),('h','i','j'),('k','l','m'),('n','o','p')]
numns = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12),(13,14,15)]

dictionary = dict()
for i in letts:
    for j in numns:
        dictionary = dict(zip(i, j))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dictionary = dict()
for i in blahh:
    dictionary[i] = dict(zip(blahh['x'][i], blahh['y'][i]))
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

You can just convert a dictionary to a DataFrame but you have to do it outside the loop, otherwise you keep overwriting your DataFrame. Note the different indentation.

Comment: Will `df_final = pd.concat([dictionary, df])` work after this?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I indented and removed concat line, but the df only has 2 columns, the index and the last column i believe

Comment: oh now I understand what you're trying to do. Please add a [mcve] so I can try stuff out.